# How to change the auto scaling group instance by the alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I am trying to change the Auto Scaling Group by alarm

My strategy is, when alarm start, one new instance will be created.

I read documents and guess I should use `StepScalingPolicy` and `StepScalingAction`

However I am not sure how can I combine these.

I made this code, but it shows error like this below.

```
  throw new Error('You must supply at least 2 intervals for autoscaling');
```

I tested again after comment-out `StepScalingPolicy`

This error also comes.

Resource handler returned message: "You should specify at least one StepAdjustment with a StepScaling policy.

```
const gpuAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, 'MemoryAlarm', {
  alarmName:metaInfo['alarmNameGpu'],
  comparisonOperator: cloudwatch.ComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_THRESHOLD,
  threshold: 30,
  evaluationPeriods: 1,
  metric:new cloudwatch.Metric({
    namespace: `tt-${targetEnv}-gpu`,
    metricName: 'GPU Usage'
  })
});

// comment out for second try.
const stepScalingPolicy = new autoscaling.StepScalingPolicy(this, 'MyStepScalingPolicy', {
  autoScalingGroup: props!.aiAutoScalingGroup,
  metric: new cloudwatch.Metric({
    namespace: `tt-${targetEnv}-gpu`,
    metricName: 'GPU Usage'
  }),
  scalingSteps: [{
    change: 1,
  }],
});
//

const stepScalingAction = new autoscaling.StepScalingAction(this, "ScaleOutAction",{
  autoScalingGroup:props!.aiAutoScalingGroup,
  adjustmentType:autoscaling.AdjustmentType.CHANGE_IN_CAPACITY
  }
);
const autoScalingAction = new actions.AutoScalingAction(stepScalingAction);
gpuAlarm.addAlarmAction(autoScalingAction);
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you test to add a dummy step like this:
{ lower: 888, upper: 999, change: 0 }, // dummy step

Comment: Thank you i try this and this error disappeared. dummy step is necessary.